# Set highcharts datalabel as dropdown list

Tags: highcharts

It's possible to set the datalabel as a dropdown menu list?

The problem appear when i have more than six label on my charts, and they overflow from the container.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: Sorry Paul, here the example http://jsfiddle.net/qwPQj/

Answer (score 0):

You want to display dataLabels for points only for one series, chosen by user via dropdown? In that case, simply update series with proper options: http://jsfiddle.net/qwPQj/1/

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Various point on range year'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Example of Highcharts JS'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'BOND'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Test1',                
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 28), 0.67],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.81],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 0.78],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 12), 0.98],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 27), 1.84],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 10), 1.80],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 18), 1.80],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 24), 1.92],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  4), 2.49],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 11), 2.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 15), 2.73],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.61],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  2), 2.76],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  6), 2.82],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 2.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4,  3), 2.1 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 26), 1.1 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  9), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5, 12), 0   ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Test2',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 18), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 26), 0.2 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  1), 0.47],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 11), 0.55],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 15), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  8), 1.48],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 21), 1.5 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 12), 1.89],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.0 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 1.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  9), 1.91],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 1.75],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), 1.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 25), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 31), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7), 0   ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Test 3',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 14), 0.15],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 28), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 12), 0.46],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.59],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 24), 0.58],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 0.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  7), 0.65],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 23), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  8), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 14), 0.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 24), 0.86],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 18), 0.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 24), 0.9 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 16), 0.39],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 21), 0   ]
            ]
        },
         {
            name: 'Test 4',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 14), 0.75],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 28), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 12), 0.46],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.59],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 24), 0.58],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 0.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  7), 0.65],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 23), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  8), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 14), 0.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 24), 2.86],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 18), 0.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 24), 0.9 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 16), 1.39],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 21), 0   ]
            ]
        },
                {
            name: 'Test5',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 28), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 16), 0.7 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 21), 0.87],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 21), 1.55],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 15), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 18), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 15), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  8), 1.48],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 21), 1.5 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 12), 1.89],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 15), 2.0 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 14), 1.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), 3.91],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 3.75],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), 1.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 25), 1.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 31), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7), 1   ]
            ]
        }]
    });
$("#s").change(function(){ 
    var selected = this.value;
    var chart =  $('#container').highcharts();

    $(chart.series).each(function(i, e) {
        e.update({
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: i == selected
            }
        }, false);
    });
    chart.redraw();
});
```

Note: You have errors in console, you should sort data for series by x-values ascending.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, but i had already thought to insert a select tag for select the series. But i would to transform the container where is all the label, in a dropdown menu. Is it possibile?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't 'see it'. Could you create simple mockup(image) how this should looks like and then describe case?